# Increase speed of applescript keystroke

Tags: performance, applescript, keystrokes

I'm using applescript to automate some browser activity. I have it tied to the speech recognition, so that I can make some custom voice commands.

One such command is "I wanna go home", which when heard, pulls up the relevant bus schedule on my browser. Given that the public transit system uses PHP and GET, the URL gets pretty long. Therefore, the `keystroke myURL` in the applescript takes a while to execute (something like 1-2 seconds). While I can live with losing 1-2 seconds, I'd really rather not.

With that in mind, is it possible to send these keystrokes faster? I believe I read somewhere that using `key code` is faster than using `keystroke`, but for the life of me, I can't figure out where I read that.

**EDIT**: My browser of choice is Google Chrome, which I couldn't find URL hooks for. This is why I had to resort to using keystrokes. Therefore, I'd prefer answers that work with Chrome over Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open location is defined in Standard Additions and should not be enclosed in a tell statement.

```
open location "http://google.com"
```

If you want to target a specific browser you can use:

```
tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    set URL of document 1 to "http://google.com"
end tell
```

To target Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    set URL of active tab of window 1 to "https://www.google.com/"
end tell
```

Comment: Though this is correct (+1), I'd prefer a solution that works with Chrome (my browser of choice - see edit)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve this is to put the text in the clipboard, then paste it. You can save the clipboard contents first and put it back afterward, so you don't lose what's already there. This method works in other situations when you want to enter a lot of text, not just for browser URLs like the other answers.

```
    set clipboard_contents to (the clipboard)
    set the clipboard to "Some long string that would take a while with the keystroke method"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
    delay 0.2 -- needed because otherwise the next command can run before the paste occurs
    set the clipboard to clipboard_contents
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can script your browser to open the URL directly, instead of typing in the keystrokes (faking input events in AppleScript should be considered a last resort).

You can do this with the `open location` standard addition:

```
open location "http://google.com"
```

Comment: No problem. Do use File->Open Dictionary...; it is extremely useful.

Comment: I did try `Open Dictionary`. Sadly, there were so few hooks for Google Chrome that I had to resort to keystrokes

Comment: As you mention, "open location" is a standard addition to applescript. Thus I'm wondering why you have that command inside a Finder tell block? You do not need the Finder to perform that command thus just use the open location line by itself.